# Best tool to work with Amazon RDS?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I just found the wonderful [ElasticFox](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/609?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1), a Firefox plugin that makes working with Amazon EC2 much more enjoyable. Is there a similar tool for Amazon RDS?

Or, rather, what is the best/easiest tool to work with RDS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS console is well enough to monitor and configure the RDS. However we cant change some parameters with AWS Console (like mysql.ini parameters). In that case you have to use [RDS Command Line tools](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/2928?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1).

Still if you dont want to mess with Command line APIs, you can use cloud management systems and use it (free edition) as GUI tool such as [RightScale](http://www.rightscale.com/)

[Here](http://amitech.co/amitech-lab/item/how-to-configurechange-myini-parameters-of-mysql-in-amazon-rds) is post you can see how third party GUI tools can be used to work with Amazon RDS

Answer (score 11):

I have been using MySQL Workbench http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/ with RDS and it works great. Very easy to create and save a new database service instance. Click "New Server Instance" under "Server Administration" and follow the prompts.  You will need to enter the information provided in the AWS RDS webpage for that instance (for example, it's endpoint).

NOTE: In order for you to actually connect, you MUST add your IP address in the "DB Security Groups."  The link is in the left-hand column, which is titled "Navigation."  I use the "CIDR/IP" option (the other is EC2 Security Group).  Make sure to include a /## after the IP, such as the /32 they use in the example.  In a few seconds, the IP address should be authorized.

After the new security group has been authorized, the "DB Security Groups" of the DB Instance running MySql needs to be updated to include this newly created security group. After this updation, the "DB Security Groups" should show atleast two 'active' security groups, one which was already present previously and other which was newly created in the previous step.

After that, go back to MySQL Workbench and complete the New Server Instance creation process.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say the [AWS Console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/) and [RDS CLI](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/2928?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1) along with MySQL client itself are totally sufficient.

Anything particular you are looking for?

Comment: Not yet, I just heard about RDS 2 minutes ago.

Comment: @ripper then I'd simply recommend to give it a try. I doubt that you need anything else than the AWS Console. The only occasions I ever go to the CLI was for purchasing reserved instances and setting some configuration parameters where the GUI was a little buggy.